# Is casting the first field of an object to the object's type actually safe?

Tags: c++, casting, undefined-behavior

At first glance, this looks like undefined behavior...

```
#include <iostream>

struct SomeBaseClass
{
    // ...
};

struct MyFakerClass
{
    SomeBaseClass base;
    void foo() { std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    MyFakerClass c;
    MyFakerClass *p = static_cast<MyFakerClass *>(static_cast<void *>(&c.base));
    p->foo();
}
```

... but if the first field of an object is guaranteed to have the same address as the object, then this must be safe, right? Or is there some other rule that intervenes?

Comment: Yes it is as long as the classes/structs are "basic" - or whatever the correct term is called.

Comment: @Mysticial: When would it not be safe, and why?

Comment: I think that as far as the class/struct is POD this is fine, but right now I don't have the willpower to dig in the standard to check :)

Comment: I don't remember the list of requirements, but the ones I can think of off the top of my head are: Non-polymorphic, all fields are also "basic". And the rule-of-zero as well. This is not comprehensive though.

Comment: @Mysticial: I understand what you're saying, but what I'm asking is slightly different: *why* is it unsafe in the case of polymorphic classes, for instance? (Is the address of the first instance field no longer guaranteed to be the same as that of the object, for instance?)

Comment: Yes, the pointer to the vtable is usually the first "field". If you just cast down, the sub-field will be on top of the vtable instead of the first field.

Comment: @Mysticial: Ah, interesting, thanks. I assumed the rule always applied regardless of the class type and therefore the vtable would need to be "behind" the object to make it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a reinterpret_cast, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa. *[ Note: There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct object, but not at its beginning, as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment. — end note ]*

(C++11, §9.2, ¶21)

So, this is safe as long as a class is "standard-layout", i.e.:

> A standard-layout class is a class that:
>
> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
> - has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
> - has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members,
> - has no non-standard-layout base classes,
> - either has no non-static data members in the most derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
> - has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.

(C++11, §9, ¶7)

All the requirements about the virtual stuff are because of the vptr: as said above, many compilers put it as a first hidden member, but they are allowed to put it anywhere or, if they are able, to omit it at all or implement virtual dispatch in other ways, so *virtual* in general alters the layout of the class in an unspecified way.

The "same access control clause" is because

> The order of allocation of non-static data members with different access control is unspecified.

(C++11, §9.2, ¶15)

I suppose that this may be to allow compilers to reorder/group the members of a class by access-control (i.e. inside the compiler the IR of a class may contain a list for the members under each access-control specifier, which does not allow to keep the original ordering - all the interleaved public/private/protected sections would be grouped and e.g. the private members may be put in front of the class by default).

The no non-standard-layout members/base classes "recursive" clauses are to ensure that the class is standard-layout as a whole (base classes and members are a part of it).

Additional details on why the rest of this stuff can affect the layout of the class may be found in §9.2.

---

Notice that this is a weaker condition than the class being POD (as I incorrectly said in the comment above), since a class is POD if it is both standard layout and *trivial* (§9 ¶10)

Comment: Just to clarify, *both* of the classes have to be standard-layout, right? [Why] is the outer class being standard-layout not sufficient by itself?

Comment: Note: The standard here lists conditions where the cast is explicitly allowed, but it never says there aren't other situations where it is also allowed. So that's what prompted my comment above -- why would the outer class being standard-layout not be sufficient for this?

Comment: I think that the member being of non-standard layout would not be a problem for this specific rule, but they put together these requirements to designate in general classes that are laid out in their entirety according to "reasonable" rules based on their data members (without having to worry about compiler-specific stuff like the eventual vptr, virtual base classes machinery & co., with the exception of padding), definition that is used also for other rules (that may have stricter requirements) and that is "useful for communicating with code written in other programming languages" (¶9)

Comment: "but it never says there aren't other situations where it is also allowed" well, what isn't explicitly allowed isn't guaranteed, so I'd say that doing this thing on non-standard layout classes is UB as far as the standard is concerned.

Comment: *"what isn't explicitly allowed isn't guaranteed"*... well, at the same time it looks to me like this *is* explicitly guaranteed, because they *do* explicitly say that a standard-layout object has the same address as its first field, which implies that it doesn't matter whether or not the inner object is standard-layout, since you'd be using the correct pointer value no matter which one you're using. What part of this reasoning is wrong?

Comment: @Mehrdad: the point is, that rule is valid until the "outer class" is standard-layout, but a standard-layout class cannot contain a non-standard-layout member. So, if your class contains a non-standard-layout member that rule isn't guaranteed anymore. I agree that in this case there should be no technical reason for this particular rule, but here we are talking about what the standard guarantees.

Comment: Ohh I see, I totally missed that part of the rule... d'oh. Thanks!